# how to Search a particular string in the followings tweets of twitter using twitter api in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

Is there a functionality to search for particular string in the tweets on twitter ????

kindly help me out..

Answer (score 0):

with the limited information that you have provided, how about this

```
var searchString = "Jam";
List<string> tweets = GetTweets();

var result = tweets.Where(tweet => tweet.Contains(searchString) );
```